# sort dictionary by multiple keys and values are string,python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Data={'name':['Sue','Sue','Jim','Lily'],
  'Date':['2013-12-11','2013-12-11','2013-11-12','2013-11-12'].
  'Time':['12:00:00','11:30:00','10:00:00','13:00:00']}
```

I want to sort dictionary by name firstly,and then sort by Date,and sort by Time lastly.like this:

```
Data={'name':['Jim','Lily','Sue','Sue'],
  'Date':['2013-11-12','2013-11-12','2013-12-11','2013-12-11'],
  'Time':['10:00:00',,'13:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00']}
```

I don`t want import any modules.

Comment: What do you mean sort dictionary? Your output shows that you are sorting  the list , which are values inside the dictionary. To me it looks like you have your data structure wrong. You need a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of `zip`s, but this sorts the items of the dictionary dependent on each other's values.

```
dict(zip(('name','Date','Time'),zip(*sorted(zip(Data['name'],Data['Date'],Data['Time'])))))
```

Which gives

```
{'Date': ('2013-11-12', '2013-11-12', '2013-12-11', '2013-12-11'), 'name': ('Jim', 'Lily', 'Sue', 'Sue'), 'Time': ('10:00:00', '13:00:00', '11:30:00', '12:00:00')}
```

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you are assuming each element in each index (of the values in the dictionary) to form a kind of a group , like one group is -

```
'name':'Sue'
'Date':'2013-12-11'
'Time':'12:00:00'
```

This seems to be a group, as I can see from your request. In such cases, you have your data structure wrong. You should be using a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is such a group above.

Example of such a list of dictionaries is -

```
Data = [{'Date': '2013-12-11', 'Time': '12:00:00', 'name': 'Sue'},
 {'Date': '2013-12-11', 'Time': '11:30:00', 'name': 'Sue'},
 {'Date': '2013-11-12', 'Time': '10:00:00', 'name': 'Jim'},
 {'Date': '2013-11-12', 'Time': '13:00:00', 'name': 'Lily'}]
```

Once this is done, you can then easily sort this list of dictionaries as -

```
sorted(Data, key = lambda x: (x['name'], x['Date'], x['Time']))
```

Giving the result -

```
[{'Date': '2013-11-12', 'Time': '10:00:00', 'name': 'Jim'},
 {'Date': '2013-11-12', 'Time': '13:00:00', 'name': 'Lily'},
 {'Date': '2013-12-11', 'Time': '11:30:00', 'name': 'Sue'},
 {'Date': '2013-12-11', 'Time': '12:00:00', 'name': 'Sue'}]
```